# Issue matching arrays to a sorted list of integers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I currently have a sorted list of scores for Players 1-4 but I'm having problems matching them to the correct players.

Take this method, for example:

```
public static void exitmethod(int[] scorep1)
{
  sort(scorep1);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     System.out.println("Player " + (i+1) + " scored " + scorep1[i] + "");
  }
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Printing the scores out this way with scores of `Player 1 = 5`, `Player 2 = 2`, `Player 3 = 2` and `Player 4 = 1` gives the ordered output as

```
Player 1 scored 1
Player 2 scored 2
Player 3 scored 2
Player 4 scored 5
```

This is clearly incorrect and I don't know how to get the correct player number to print with it's correspoding score. A nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: create a class of player with id and score and use http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/ for soring your player class

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using a TreeMap<> so one doesn't need to define another class just map each score to its player.

```
int scores[] = {7, 3, 1, 2, 4};
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    map.put(scores[i], i);
}
System.out.println("map = " + map);
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("player " + e.getValue() + " scored " + e.getKey());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default [Array.sort(int[]) gives you ascending](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) results instead of descending.

You could create your own Comparator and pass that in as agrument to the appropriate [List::sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method, since you say you already "have a sorted **list**".

It doesn't seem there is a version of Arrays.sort() which also takes a Comparator argument.

Edit:
See also @Haider's comment for examples.

Comment: Don't have enough rep. to post this link to the [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) documentation...